# Name of the service that shows your site even when it's down

Tags: web-services

I've seen meme sites that show their static site files even when they're down. I can't remember the name of that service, and google searches are coming up with nothing. I've tried "service that shows site when down", "show static files when website is down", etc...can't find the thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY FOUND ANOTHER SITE THAT WAS DOWN USING IT. IT'S CALLED CLOUDFLARE. 
https://www.cloudflare.com/index

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the WayBack machine?

http://archive.org/web/

Here are four services that speed up your site time by real-time caching, but I don't know how it operates when you site is truly down:

http://www.akamai.com/ (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-cloudappcomfeatures/)

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

http://www.fastly.com/products/real-time-cache

http://www.incapsula.com/tour/website-performance

Ok, last stab at this -- this is really not a caching solution, but would DNS failover work for you where if your site is down, you have a secondary site set up at different DNS location?

http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/services/dns-failover-system-monitoring/

http://dyn.com/managed-dns/active-failover/

Comment: No, it's real time and tracks your site going down, then displays files from it's servers instead.

Comment: None of those are quite what I was looking for either, but I do appreciate all your suggestions/help.

Comment: Lol Still not quite the same service as I was seeing, but that's the gist of it. Thank you again!

Comment: FOUND IT! cloudflare!